# How to Display the Manualy added data one by one in to ListView via ArrayAdapter of object class

Tags: android, arrays, android-layout, arraylist, android-listview

I am displaying the Data in to ListView as like below code:

```
private class OrderAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Employer> {

    private ArrayList<Employer> items;

    public OrderAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Employer> items) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
            this.items = items;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = convertView;
            if (v == null) {
                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v = vi.inflate(R.layout.paye_list_row, null);
            }
            Employer o = items.get(position);
            if (o != null) {
                    TextView tt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.toptext);
                    TextView bt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.value);

                    if (tt != null) {
                        tt.setText(o.getOrderName()); // Setting the Value here      

                    }
                    if(bt != null){

                        if(position==0)
                           bt.setText(o.getTaxcode()); // Setting the Value here
                        if(position==1)
                            bt.setText(o.getPayPeriod()); // Setting the Value here
                        if(position==2)
                            bt.setText(o.getPayFrequency()); // Setting the Value here
                        if(position==3)
                            bt.setText(o.getSalaryWage()); // Setting the Value here
                        if(position==4)
                            bt.setText(o.getNetGrossAmount()); // Setting the Value here
                        if(position==5)
                            bt.setText(o.getKiwiSaverMember()); // Setting the Value here
                        if(position==6)
                            bt.setText(o.getEmployeeDeduction()); // Setting the Value here
                        if(position==7)
                            bt.setText(o.getEmployeeContribution()); // Setting the Value here
                        if(position==8)
                            bt.setText(o.getComplyingFundMember()); // Setting the Value here
                        if(position==9)
                            bt.setText(o.getFundContribution()); // Setting the Value here
                        if(position==10)
                            bt.setText(o.getESCTTaxRate()); // Setting the Value here
                        if(position==11)
                            bt.setText(o.getChildSupportDeduction()); // Setting the Value here
                        if(position==12)
                            bt.setText(o.getPayrollDonation()); // Setting the Value here

                    }
            }
            return v;
    }
}
```

And i am adding the data manualy to my another ArrayList like below code:

```
// Set Employee one by one
                ArrayList<Employer> tempEmployerList = employerList;
                System.out.println("=================================" +
                        "=IN end Document================================");
                System.out.println(" tempEmployerList Size:" +tempEmployerList.size());
                Employer m = new Employer();
                //  My Code for to add data
                m = new Employer();
                m.setTaxcode(taxCodeValue);
                m.setPayPeriod(payPeriodValue);
                m.setPayFrequency(payFrequencyValue);
                m.setSalaryWage(salaryWageValue);
                m.setNetGrossAmount("Gross");
                m.setKiwiSaverMember(kiwiSaverMemberValue);
                m.setEmployeeDeduction(employeeDeductionValue);
                m .setEmployeeContribution(employeeContributionValue);
                m.setComplyingFundMember(complyingFundMemberValue);
                m.setFundContribution(fundContributionValue);
                m.setESCTTaxRate(ESCTTaxRateValue);
                m.setChildSupportDeduction(childSupportDeductionValue);
                m.setPayrollDonation(payrollDonationValue);
                employerList.add(m);
```

If I want to display that data in log cat then i can see it by below code:

```
//  TO DISPLAY DATA
                for(int j=0;j<tempEmployerList.size();j++)
                {
                    System.out.println("================ Employee: "+(j+1)+"======================");
                    m = new Employer();

                    m=tempEmployerList.get(j);
                    //System.out.println("TaxCodeHeading: "+(j+1)+" = "+m.getOrderName());
                    System.out.println("TaxCode: "+(j+1)+" = "+m.getTaxcode());
                    System.out.println("PayPeriod: "+(j+1)+" = "+m.getPayPeriod());
                    System.out.println("Frequency: "+(j+1)+" = "+m.getPayFrequency());
                    System.out.println("Salary/Wage: "+(j+1)+" = "+m.getSalaryWage());
                    System.out.println("NetGross Amount: "+(j+1)+" = "+m.getNetGrossAmount());
                    System.out.println("KiwiSaverMember: "+(j+1)+" = "+m.getKiwiSaverMember());
                    System.out.println("Employee Deduction: "+(j+1)+" = "+m.getEmployeeDeduction());
                    System.out.println("Complying Fund Member: "+(j+1)+" = "+m.getComplyingFundMember());
                    System.out.println("Fund Contribution: "+(j+1)+" = "+m.getFundContribution());
                    System.out.println("ESCT Tax Rate: "+(j+1)+" = "+m.getESCTTaxRate());
                    System.out.println("Child Support Deduction: "+(j+1)+" = "+m.getChildSupportDeduction());
                    System.out.println("Payroll giving Donation: "+(j+1)+" = "+m.getPayrollDonation());
                }
```

All Works fine. But now if i have added more then one employee then i want to display it on the List view one by one on the click of the next button click.

So how it is Possible.
Please help me for that.
Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using a list view ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare an Employee Object as a Field in Activity, and load your adapter data from that field, in case of next and previous button event change Employer object to next or previous item in list and call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() method.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you're trying to use a ListView to display different values of the employer object.  This is a misuse of the ListView, which is generally used to display a collection of arbitrary length, with similar entities represented by each row in the list.

In this case, you would be better to simply create a simple form of vertically stacked label & field widgets.  These could be placed into a ScrollView so that the whole thing could be larger than the display area.  The prev / next buttons would simply update this form with the current employer information.  This approach would be much simpler and more efficient than a ListView.

Comment: Yes thanks for the answer but i have to use listView thats why i am using it. Thanks a lot.